# tokenize in excel to extract substring only

Tags: excel

for example : 76-221-161-164.lightspeed.cicril.sbcglobal.net

I want to remove the hostname : 76-221-161-164.
I want to remove the TLD: .net 
I want to keep: lightspeed.cicril.sbcglobal

also
in different exercise I want to

I want to keep: sbcglobal.net

Other example are:

host60-7-dynamic.48-82-r.retail.telecomitalia.it
117.120.132.27.ap.yournet.ne.jp
ip-phone-193-157-180-126.uio.no
host251-107-dynamic.53-82-r.retail.telecomitalia.it
238.sub-97-232-125.myvzw.com
node-5wo.pool-118-174.dynamic.totbb.net
218-172-44-88.dynamic.hinet.net
host-95-196-129-181.mobileonline.telia.com

Comment: I have list of 1 million rows with different number of dots

Comment: more examples: host60-7-dynamic.48-82-r.retail.telecomitalia.it
117.120.132.27.ap.yournet.ne.jp
ip-phone-193-157-180-126.uio.no
host251-107-dynamic.53-82-r.retail.telecomitalia.it
238.sub-97-232-125.myvzw.com
node-5wo.pool-118-174.dynamic.totbb.net
218-172-44-88.dynamic.hinet.net
host-95-196-129-181.mobileonline.telia.com

Comment: I want to remove the first sub-string ends with "." and the last substring starts with "." and keeps the middle string.

Comment: Read [ask] to see why you've got downvotes.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you want to remove the first and last text-string, try this simple macro:

```
Sub FixPhrases()
    Dim r As Range, sOut As String
        For Each r In Selection
            ary = Split(r.Value, ".")
            sOut = ary(1)
            For i = 2 To UBound(ary) - 1
                sOut = sOut & "." & ary(i)
            Next i
            r.Value = sOut
        Next r
End Sub
```